# Why invoke Telegram Bot API reported error msg : "chat not found"

Tags: bots, telegram

I  use Telegram Bot  API to send a messsage to my account ,but return the error msg "Bad Request:chat not found",I have check  my  bot's token and account's  chat_id is no problem,after search in google,the  answer is i must   send a message to the  bot first ,then the Bot API can  invoke  success.But ,  it is so trouble ! I  can't tell my software's user ,they  must send  a msg to  bot  in telegram  first,it is unacceptable！Is  there  any other way  ?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want to send message to the user when user has not started using your bot. Am I right?

If so, you can not send a message to a user, who is not using your bot.

If you have another problem, you need to share your code or tell us more.

Comment: Thanks very much! As you said , my telegram user yet not talk to bot,   i want to use bot api to send message 。Until now , it  seems not way to done it.

Comment: Yes, you can't. If you want to send a message to user you need to use Telegram API. For Python I know 'telethon' library, it gives you the opportunity to do so

Comment: OK! Thanks!   Let me  have a try !